# Are there any sure fire hangover cures?

Tags: hangover, science

The internet is full of hangover cures - (I need a drink just reading them all!)

Just how many can claim to be backed by science?

Obvious strategies include staying hydrated, getting plenty of sleep, eating a good breakfast and taking certain supplements, all of which could reduce your hangover symptoms.

But is there an instant cure?

Comment: [Drinking less is the obvious solution.](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/a/6299/5064)

Comment: @Ken Graham. Um - that would involve a bit of moderation!

Comment: black bitter coffee, for me

Answer (score 1):

There is no cure for a hangover except to not drink in the first place.

Comment: Great to see someone working for the site.  I apologise for the question - just thought we needed a bit of uumph out there..... however, on this site, NOT DRINKING, give me a break..........  I'm off for a gin......by the way it's a bit windy here, so have to have to rescue a boat or two.......